# What is the use of "projects" option in github?

Tags: github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoOoK.jpg)

Do I need to use that option everytime I work with my code? I have never used that option till now though.

Comment: Go through the link - https://help.github.com/articles/about-projects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projects on GitHub are recently released feature that adds a kanban-style board to your repository. Projects are made up of issues, pull requests, and notes that are categorized as cards in columns of your choosing. Cards can be moved from column to column and reordered according to your needs. Read here for more details: https://help.github.com/articles/about-projects/

The main takeaway is that you DO NOT have to use Projects. The projects tab is completely optional. You can completely ignore this feature with no consequences to the code in your repository.